# Failing to run Turtle Graphics program on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm a Python newbie working on my first Turtle Graphics program.

This is what I have at the moment

```
import turtle

def draw_square():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("red")

    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.forward(100)

    window.exitonclick()

draw_square()
```

This code works perfectly on my friend's Windows laptop:
[image: windows]
However, problem arises when we tried to run it on my Macbook. The issue we were facing is that Python Turtle Graphics displays nothing as below:
[image: macos]

Why can't my program run normally on MacOS? And how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue that arises due to an incompatibility between MacOS and `Tkinter`, on which `Turtle` is based. In the terminal, use the following code:

```
brew install tcl-tk
env \
  PATH="$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/bin:$PATH" \
  LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/lib" \
  CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/include" \
  PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/lib/pkgconfig" \
  CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/include" \
  PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-tcltk-includes='-I$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6'" \
  pyenv install 3.8.13
```